# FB Developer app , need to create a user_access_token by using server api

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, backend, react-fullstack

Not able to generate a user_Access_Token by using api server .

Able to generate a app_token but not able to access user details with this token

I need a request api to create a user_Access _Token for fb developers app.

Help.....